# Successfully deleted an element in a vector but wondering how it effects the other elements and how can I re order the vector?

Tags: c++, console-application

I am currently making a little inventory system with c++ and I am having an issue. My string vector consists of three elements: 'boots', 'cloak' and a 'sword' and has a limit of 5 elements. I am wanting to delete certain elements for selling of items and other related things.

When deleting the sword by the following code `inventory.erase(inventory.begin())` The first element - inventory[0] is erased but my issue is how does it effect and relate to the other two elements - `inventory[1]` & `inventory[2]`.

When printing the elements of the inventory the first one prints blank but the other two are still there within their already assigned elements. Is there a way to re order the vector so that `inventory[1]` becomes `inventory[0]` and can I just add another element into `inventory[0]` without any errors if it was erased?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::vector erase member function does what you want.  After you erase the first element inventory.erase(inventory.begin()), there should only be two elements left: inventory[0] is "cloak" and inventory[1] is "sword".